# Are objects in Perl can only be declared inside packages?

Tags: perl, oop

Cant I do something like

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Horse; #this is the package

my $test;

bless $test,Horse;
```

Does that code above instantiate `$test` as an object reference to Horse package? Or Objects in Perl are just packages which "already have `bless` statements" waiting to be instantiated?

Also, can you provide sample accessing on object variables or methods or functions? whatever it is called in Perl?

Comment: (1) Objects cannot be "declared", period.  (2) The above code dies.  A lot.  (3) The best way to get an answer out of SO is to describe what you are trying to do.  (4) To get examples of how to use objects in Perl, look up "objects" in the Perl documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bless` builtin tags a reference with a package name. That package is then used to resolve methods that are called on the object. So even without an explicit package, one could do

```
my $obj = bless { x => 1}, 'Foo';

sub Foo::x {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->{x};
}

print "1 == ", $obj->x, "\n";
```

Note that you should quote the package name given to `bless`.

So yes, you can bless a reference into any class, including a class that was imported. But be aware that this doesn't run constructors, and breaks “encapsulation”, an object oriented principle that you should only use methods to interact with a class/with an object (e.g. the `new`  class method).

---

#### Edit: Fully qualified names

Each global variable has a fully qualified name, which consists of the package name plus the variable name. Subroutines are just a special kind of variable. For example, this:

```
$Some::Package::var = 5;
sub Some::Package::give_var { return $Some::Package::var }
```

is roughly the same thing as

```
{
  package Some::Package; # package declaration opens a new namespace
  our $var = 5;
  sub give_var { return $var }
}
```

Therefore, `sub Foo::x {...}` declares a sub named `x` in the package `Foo`.

Comment: @user2492415 No, that is the whole point. However, the `sub Foo::x {...}` implicitly creates the `Foo` package. (Packages are not files, and there is no requirement for a 1:1-mapping)

Comment: You don't need a Foo.pm file. This is a quite an odd thing to do though.

Comment: what does this statement means - `Foo::x`? is x the variable referred in the anonymous hash? Can you please edit your answer and include an explanation why your subroutine is written in that weird manner? I only see `::` in packages.

Comment: And also are you saying the `bless` statement is intended or suggested to be used inside packages?

Comment: The purpose of `bless` is to create a relationship between a reference and a package, but this can be done from anywhere.

Comment: @user2492415 See my edit for `Foo::x` explanation. I suggest to never use `bless` outside the package that you are blessing into, but each rule has exceptions. I sometimes use `bless` to add quite arbitrary data, e.g. in tokenizers.